# Simple loop inside template -- variable 'x' cannot be read at compile time

Tags: metaprogramming, d, template-meta-programming

*(Note that I am extremely new to DLang (first day) so I am probably doing something very stupid)*

I am trying to create a mixin template to re-use in my app's domain classes, which will automatically generate a `toString1()` method at compile-time, which will loop through the implementing `struct`'s properties and generate code to print them.

To accomplish this, I am getting a `const` array of all of the struct's properties and trying to loop through them. However, when I try to access the index inside the loop (which should be perfectly executable at compile-time -- since we are looping against a known value) it fails.

It works completely fine if I use hard-coded indexes.

```d
template Printable() {
    import std.algorithm.iteration;
    import std.conv;
    import std.meta;
    import std.stdio;
    import std.format;
    import std.range;
    import std.typecons;

    string toString1() const {
        const auto traits = __traits(allMembers, typeof(this));
        const auto internalWrap = (const string s) => "`" ~ s ~ ": ` ~ this." ~ s ~ " ~ `\n`";

        const auto ret = iota(0, traits.length)
            .map!((const int x) => traits[x])       // Error: variable x cannot be read at compile time
            .fold((a, b) => a ~ b);

        pragma(msg, internalWrap(traits[0]));       // WORKS GREAT
        
        
        return "";
    }
}
```

(Just a note that I also tried doing it using both for-loops as well, but it fails with the same error).

Comment: you'd probably be better off just directly running `foreach` over the `__traits` bit, removing the intermediate variables. I'm short on time to write tonight but compile time execution is very much context dependent - it is only triggered in certain contexts and can only use variables from the right contexts. In your specific code, the `iota.map` shifts you out of compile time and into run time. I suspect if you did `alias traits = ...` instead of `const auto` it might work anyway, but generally the more layers you put in the more likely you are to lose compile time context in the process.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thank you for such a fast response. Using `foreach` was actually my first approach, but `__traits` returns a `tuple` that it appears cannot be iterated over. I searched for a few hours on how to convert a tuple to an array with no luck.

Comment: tuples can be iterated over, it should just work. `foreach(name; __traits(allMembers, X)) { /* use name */ }`. In some contexts you are better off doing `static foreach(same) {}`, the difference is in introducing scope and allowing use in declaration context. I can write more perhaps tomorrow or Monday about this. Also tuple to array - assuming all tuple elements are of same type (they don't have to be!) is as simple as putting `[]` around it. e.g. `[__traits(allMembers, X)]`. tuples are weird but cool once you get to know them.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thanks again! I got the `foreach` working fine, not sure why it wasn't before (probably due to my own tunnel vision and having messed something else up). I still can't get it to concatenate a string though, but it's ok -- I think I got it working enough to where it's useful for me (by having it emit a series of `writeln` statements instead of constructing a string to return). I should probably get more familiar with the language before delving into this area of it anyway. Thanks again

Comment: concatenating into a string at compile time needs to be wrapped up in a function. you can only modify local variables 100% inside the compile time context in CTFE. Once you return it it needs to go back to static/immutable/whatever. Hopefully I'll have the time later to write this all up with some background explanation as an answer and that should help understand the bigger picture...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put an answer on this so this is a code example about what we went over in the comments:

```
struct A {
        int a;
        string b;

        mixin Printable; // adds the toString1 method
}

mixin template Printable() {
        string toString1() const {
                string s;

                import std.conv;

                // loop over the trait directly, don't try to feed it
                // through variables to ensure still available
                foreach(memberName; __traits(allMembers, typeof(this))) {
                        // this ensures we are only actually trying to print actual fields
                        // (only fields have an offsetof property) since printing member
                        // variables will not be helpful
                        static if(is(typeof(__traits(getMember, this, memberName).offsetof))) {
                                if(s.length)
                                        s ~= "\n";
                                // name
                                s ~= memberName;
                                s ~= " = ";
                                // value, converted to string
                                s ~= to!string(__traits(getMember, this, memberName));
                        }
                }

                return s;
        }
}


void main() {
        import std.stdio;

        A a = A(14, "string");

        writeln(a.toString1());
}
```

prints

```
a = 14
b = string
```